# TableView Cell Delegates (Qt.BackgroundRole)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am struggling to get what seems to be a simple delegate working.

What I want is to change the background of a tableview cell. From what I understand
I should be looking at the Qt.BackgroundRole. So far I havent been able to get it working, or find a relevant example.

What I have so far, is a delegate that fills the cell with a color, but it seems to be going
on top of the text. what I want is the text to remain, and to change only the background of the cell.

```
class CellBackgroundColor(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):       

        path = index.model().data(index,  QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor(path))
```

Any ideas on how to implement this Qt.BackgroundRole in a tableview delegate?

Thanks in advance,
Cris

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a delegate to paint the cell background; the default delegate supports background painting through `Qt.BackgroundRole`:

```
class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    ...
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QColor(...)
```

Otherwise it's a good idea to use `initStyleOption` to initialise the  `QStyleOptionViewItem` and paint that with any appropriate overrides:

```
class CellBackgroundColor(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    ...
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        # override background
        option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QColor(...)
        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, widget)
```

Comment: Hi ecatmur, thanks a lot for your reply. How exactly do you override the background in your second example?

Comment: @user1028826 you can set `backgroundBrush`: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstyleoptionviewitemv4.html#backgroundBrush-var

Comment: Thanks a lot got it working now,  your second example works perfectly. Cheers have a great week!